# Gradient based sensitivity analysis of roll & pitch Euler Angles (ZYX convention)

Tags: partial-derivative, chain-rule, singularity, jacobian

I'm trying to analytically create the sensitivity function for simple Euler Angle in intrinsic ZYX convention (sometimes called Tait Bryan angles), see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles#Rotation_matrix. Let's start with the projection of a full ZYX rotation matrix to the vector of gravity $[0, 0, 1]^T$, see https://www.nxp.com/files-static/sensors/doc/app_note/AN3461.pdf, page 7.
[image]
Now assume that I have an accelerometer that measures the *negative* components of this gravity vector so that
$$\begin{bmatrix}
a_x\\a_y\\a_z
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \sin\theta\\-\cos\theta \sin\phi\\-\cos\theta \cos\phi\end{bmatrix}
$$
Please note the change of sign. From that, the so-called roll ($\phi$) and pitch ($\theta$) angles can be calculated:
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\tan\phi&=\frac{-a_y}{-a_z}\quad (1) \\\tan\theta&=\frac{a_x\cos\phi}{-a_z} \quad (2) \\ &=\frac{a_x}{\sqrt{a_y^2+a_z^2}} \quad (3)
\end{eqnarray}
$$

What I like to have is the sensitivity function, i.e. the partial derivatives of $\phi$. This is relatively straight forward in the shown formulation, (1) being a function of $a_y$ and $a_z$. However, I'd like to have this parametrized in terms of $\theta$ and $\phi$ to plot the sensitivity function $J_\phi(\theta,\phi)$ for roll/$\phi$.

Since (2) contains both, $\phi$ and $\theta$, I tried to do something like that (starting from (2)).

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\tan\theta=\frac{a_x\cos\phi}{-a_z} \\ \Leftrightarrow 
\cos\phi=\frac{-a_z \tan\theta}{a_x} \\ \Leftrightarrow 
\phi = \arccos\frac{-a_z \tan\theta}{a_x} \\
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Let's denote that with $\phi=f(x(\theta))=\arccos(x(\theta))$, with $x=\frac{-a_z \tan\theta}{a_x}$, i.e. I need to apply the chain rule for the partial derivatives:
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial\theta}=
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}=
\frac{-1}{\sqrt{1-(\frac{-a_z \tan\theta}{a_x})^2}}\cdot({-(1+\tan^2\theta)\frac{a_z}{a_x}})=
\frac{a_z\sec^2(\theta)}{a_x\sqrt{1-\frac{a_z^2 \tan^2\theta}{a_x^2}}}
$$

However this seems to be wrong. I know, that the sensitivity should be high for larger values of $\theta$, something like the first plot, but it's the other way round (singularities in the middle)

[image]
[image]

I think, there is conceptional mistake, probably since $a_y$ and $a_z$ are functions of $\theta$, too.

What is the correct way to solve this problem? I guess first $a_y$ and $a_z$ should be eliminated to have a pure function of $\theta$ and $\phi$, is that correct?

Any hints are very much appreciated, thank you!